# Get $state.current (ui-router) into $http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-ui-router

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I would like to get value of data of the current state in my $http interceptor. I have already created the interceptor.

**Problem**

I don't know how to catch $state.current.data in my interceptor. I try to use $injector.get($state) but in can't read property of the object.

```coffee
 angular.module('mymodule').factory 'HttpInterceptor', [
 '$location', '$injector'
  ($location, $injector) ->

  request: (config) ->
   # Do something when sending the request
   console.log(config.headers.hasOwnProperty('Authorization'))
   if config.headers.hasOwnProperty('Authorization') == false
    $location.url("/login")
   config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be able to give you an idea of how you can achieve it through the run block.

```
app.run(function (StateInterceptor, FPSSO, HTTPResponseCode, $state, SessionManager, notifications, Utils, $timeout) {
  StateInterceptor.startService();

  var httpSecurityInterceptor =  function(response, deferred){
    var propagatePromise = true;
    switch(response.status){
      case HTTPResponseCode.UNAUTHORIZED:
        SessionManager.Logout();
        notifications.showErrorMessage("Your session has expired. Please sign in again.", "Error");
        $state.go('Logout', {isLogout: true, returnUrl: $state.current.name});  
        propagatePromise = false;  
        break;
      default:
        var res = Utils.ExtractResponse(response);
        res.status = response.status;
        deferred.reject(res);
    }
    return propagatePromise;
  }

  FPSSO.API.setErrorInterceptor(httpSecurityInterceptor);
```

You can see that in the Unauthorized case of the switch statement, I am able to access the $state.current and route my app to 'Logout'. This is a code that is deployed on production so I am pretty sure it works.

Try to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with $state behavior, but you can create a service that stores the current data of a state and get it inside the injector.

Answer (score 0):

I can inject $state properly using the following code in my interceptor:

```
   $timeout(function () {
                    $state = $injector.get('$state');
                });
```